# Compiler error when calling connect(2) with sockaddr_un

Tags: c++, network-programming, ipc, unix-socket

I am making a simple call to connect(2), in a C++ program.  The code is:

`connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&name, SUN_LEN(name));`

(here, `name` is a `struct sockaddr_un`).

When I try to compile this, I get the following error from g++:

```
error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'sockaddr_un'
```

I am totally baffled by this, because I'm not using the -> operator anywhere in the program!  Is there something wrong with the way I'm taking the address of `name`, or the way I am casting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `SUN_LEN` expects the passed structure to be a pointer, so you should use `SUN_LEN(&name)`.